# C++ working with pointers

Tags: c++

I don't understand why it outputs "123" even though the deletenode function set x to NULL.

```
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;
struct node {int value; struct node *left,*right,*parent;};
void deletenode(node *a) {
    delete a;
    a=NULL;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    node *x = new node;
    x->value=123;
    deletenode(x);
    if (x!=NULL) cout << x->value;
}
```

Comment: A pointer is not a reference. Please read a good beginner C++ book before asking trivial questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following signature: `void deletenode(node *a)`. You pass a pointer `x` to the function. The pointer value gets *copied*. Inside the function, you modify the local pointer value by writing to it via `a = NULL`.

However, that modification happens on the copy. The original remains unaffected. Notice that this isn’t true for `delete`, since `delete` doesn’t modify the pointer, it modifies (or rather, purges) the *pointee*.

The superficial solution is to pass the pointer value by reference:

```
void deletenode(node*& a)
```

However, there’s a consensus that setting pointers to `nullptr` (or `NULL`) after deletion doesn’t really help, and is therefore not normally done. I would therefore replace your whole call to `deletenode` with a simple `delete x;` statement.

Comment: Thank you very much, but actually I have a problem with deleting a node in a binary tree so I can't use "delete" as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Although you've successfully deleted the object you intended to, the pointer itself is passed by value (copied to variable 'a') to deletenode(). So even though variable 'a' inside the function is null, variable 'x' is still pointing to the now-deleted memory.

Answer (score 0):

Because with **delete** you are actually marking the memory as free and ready to be reused, but the content of the area is probably left untouched

Answer (score 0):

You pass this pointer to the function BY VALUE - this means you wont see changes outside of the function. Try to pass it by reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void destroy(T*& ptr) {
  delete ptr;
  ptr = NULL;
}

template<typename T>
struct node {
  node(T t) : value(t) { }
  ~node() {
    delete left;
    delete right;
  }
  T value;
  struct node *left,*right,*parent;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  node<int> *x = new node<int>(123);

  destroy(x);

  if (x != NULL) {
    std::cout << x->value << '\n';
  }
}
```